# Clustering a variable based on another variable or set of variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, algorithms

```
df11[['COMPONENT_ID','FIRMWARE','SERIAL','CRP0_VDDN']].head()
```

[image]

Consider I have these four columns to analyse. I want to form say 3-5 clusters of COMPONENT_IDs with similar characters. I want this to happen based on the remaining features or just CRPO_VDNN in relation with COMPONENT_IDs. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, clustering is used only for numeric values, especially for continuous values. What you are trying to do here is to cluster a categorical variable, that too an ID column. I'm unsure about the goal but this is not a good technique to cluster values.

That being said, I'm not sure how many unique entries you have in the ID column. You have to convert it into categorical numbers before clustering. Then take only the ID column and the CRPO_VDNN column and use KNN to cluster. You can set the number of clusters in the KNN too.

Comment: Ok there are 386 unique values in component_Id , the name suggests id butit is not index. There are duplicates of ids in the rows. Is there no possibility that among 386 component_ids 100 of them belong to CRPO_VDNN of range 1-1.1 and the other 150 in range 1-1.2 and remaining forms another cluster. This is just and example I mentioned. The Goal of this task would be I want to replace those component IDs something like it belongs to either 'HIGH' voltage or 'Medium' or 'Low' voltage(CRPO_VDNN). Hence I remove the ID dependency and introduce a character of those IDs